# A Question on Stabilizers

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Consider the following proposition: 
Let $K/F$ be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$, and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. $K$ and $F$ here have characteristic 0. Prove that there exists an element $β ∈ K$ whose stabilizer is equal to $H$.

Here are my ideas:

(1) Since $K/F$ is finite and $char(F) = 0$, there exists a $\gamma \in K$ such that $K = F(\gamma)$. (The Primitive Elements Theorem)

(2) Consider the stabilizer of $\gamma: Stab(\gamma)  = \{\sigma \in H | \sigma(\gamma) = \gamma\}$ (Is this correct definition of the stabilizer here?)

(3) Indeed $Stab(\gamma) \subset H$

(4) How do I show that $H \subset Stab(\gamma)$? Can anyone show me a way to move forward?

Comment: Characteristic zero implies that the fields have *infinitely* many elements, so the tag [tag:finite-fields] was inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $L=\{x\in K, h(x)=x,h\in H\}$, $L$ is a subfield of $K$. The primitive element implies that $L=F(a)$, $H\subset Stab(a)$ since $a\in L$.

Let $g:g(a)=a$, let $x\in L, x=c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2+..+c_na^n$ $c_i\in F$ since $L=F(a)$, this implies that $g(x)=g(c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2+..+c_na^n)=c_0+c_1g(a)+..+c_ng(a_n)=c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2+..+c_na^n=x$, we deduce that for every $x\in L, g(x)=x$, implies $g\in H$ and $Stab(a)=H$.

Comment: Was my definition of the stabilizer correct? Can you explain why you said $H \subset Stab(a)$ in the first paragraph? I just thought that $Stab(a) \subset H$ because the stabilizer consists of only automorphisms in H.

Comment: It is $H\subset Stab(a)$, this is true because $a\in L$ and $L=\{x\in K,h(x)=x\}$ for every $h\in H$.

Comment: @Tsemos Aristide How do you know that L = F(a)? Don't we have to know that L/F is Galois, or equivalently that Aut(K/L) is normal subgroup of Aut(K/F)? How do you show this?

Comment: because the characteristic is zero, so the extension is separable. The primitive element theorem can be used.

Comment: @ Tsemos Aristide Can you explain more. Want do you mean extension is separable?

Comment: @Tsemos Aristide Is there a way to show that L/F is Galois? How does that separable extension show this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension

Comment: @Tsemos Aristide: Is this logic correct: K/F is finite $\to$ K is finite $\to$ L is finite $\to$ L/F is finite extension?

Comment: Is L an algebraic extension of F